# Completely remove package (GIMP), including all settings

Tags: apt, software-installation, gimp

Somehow I've gone and messed up my GIMP settings -- the application looks all messed up to the point where I can't even find the menus. See below:

[image]

I'm not interested in trying to fix it through GIMP itself, I just want to reinstall with default settings. I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove gimp
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install gimp


sudo apt-get purge gimp
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

and in both cases, when I reinstall GIMP, it still has all my old settings like in the picture. Is there a directory I have to delete somewhere? Why isn't apt removing my settings for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try deleting `~/.gimp`. If you can't find that, it might be called something else, like `~/.gimp-2.6`.

Note: Newer versions of GIMP may differ; for example, GIMP 2.10 might be in `~/.config/GIMP/2.10`.

Comment: Hey that  worked, thanks! Do you think that the expected behavior for a user would/should be to have all these settings purged when removed/purged? Is this something that should be brought up in a Gimp or Apt issue tracker or other feedback mechanism?

Comment: @JoshLemer AFAIK the intent of `apt-get purge` is to remove *system* configuration files - since Linux follows a multi-user model,  it is considered bad practice for administrative commands to mess with a *user's* config files

Answer (score 8):

Since this question resurfaced, try in that order:

- **Edit > Preferences > Windows management** -> **Reset saved window positions do default values** (other Preference tabs also have a button to reset settings to defaults: **Tool options**, **Interface**, **Input devices**)
- In the [Gimp profile](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/), erase the `sessionrc` file (which is where windows positions are remembered)
- Rename the Gimp profile (so Gimp recreates one, and you can copy useful things form the old to the new)
- Reinstall Gimp (but never had to go that far)

Comment: Thank you! The link (Gimp profile) was useful. You see, on my computer the GIMP's settings are in the map /home/igor/snap/gimp/322/.config/GIMP/2.10 I would never guess that (looking for something like /home/igor/.gimp). Also uninstalling gimp has not worked as it had obviously been installed by some package. :-(

Answer (score 5):

I knows it's a very late answer, but this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove gimp
```

Comment: Normally completely useless to reinstall Gimp, renaming the profile is enough in 99.99% of the cases.

Answer (score 3):

For the ones who have used Ubuntu Software to install it which now for some reason does not load, try:

```
snap remove gimp
```

Add a sudo if neccessary

Comment: thanks, this worked for me!